# Visual Studio 2005: Please stop opening my CS files in "Design Mode"!

Tags: visual-studio, designer

I think it's associating my Web Service's CS files with the related ASMX files.  But whatever's happening, I can't double-click to open the CS files - I have to "view Code" or it opens in the designer.

Anyone know how to turn off this automatic behavior?  I just want to edit the code!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try right-clicking, select "Open with...", mark "CSharp Editor" and select "Set as Default".

That works for avoiding the WinForms Designer.

Comment: Brian's answer is better cause it fixes this for the whole team, not just yourself https://stackoverflow.com/a/714418/56621

Answer (score 7):

I found this question when trying to deal with a similar problem.  I had a C# class in a file and whenever I double clicked on the file it would try to open in design mode but design mode was meaningless for this class.  I just want to see the code.

I found that adding the [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")] attribute to my class fixed this.

Comment: I like this answer cause it fixes the problem not just for me (like Rasmuses answer) but for all my team! (I had a class derived from WebClient, which inherits ComponentModel and it this was really annoying)

Comment: @brian-ensink Could you please fix the broken link.

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer view, click the "Show All Files" icon. This will put "+" symbol next to each of your files. Click the + and it will expand to show the .CS file which holds the ASMX's code. At this point, double click that file instead.

Comment: Thank you - but my web service CS and ASMX files are actually decoupled (CS are in a different folder and not bundled under ASMX as default) and when I click on those it still opens in designer :(

Answer (score 0):

For some reason VS2005 seems to have this a bit backwards when it comes to webservices.  To open a webservice in code view, double-click the .asmx file, not the .asmx.cs file.

I guess it makes a bit of sense, as there's nothing to "design" when it comes to a webservice, but it's counterintuitive if you've been working with .aspx files.

Comment: Yep - it's exactly this backwards behavior that I'm hoping I can remove :(  I hope that someone knows if it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you find that the wrote editor, that is the non-default editor, is opening when double-clicking on a file within the **Solution Explorer** then something is wrong with the underlying project's **User Options** file (.user) or the solution's **User Options** file (.suo). (I am not sure which, but I suspect the settings are stored in the .suo file.) Deleting the the .suo and all project .user files solved the problem.

I personally, set the **Form Editor** as my default editor for forms at the beginning of a project. After the forms are stable and require less user-interface design changes, I switch the default editor.